# Spring Data Rest only use path with parent

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, spring-data-rest

Short Description: I want spring-data-rest to only generate endpoints like "/users/{userId}/settings", "/users/{userId}/values" and not "/settings" or "/values".

More Details:

I started to get annoyed with checking in every controller function whether the logged in user has access to the requested resource and had the following idea to automate it (if someone has a better idea which doesn't cause the problems below, I would be happy to hear)

In my application the user only has access to his own resource and can't see any data of other users.

So my idea was to restrict (with the Websecurity config) all paths starting with "/users/{id}**" to only allow access when the logged in user has the given id.
That way if my endpoints are e.g. "/users/{userId}/userValues"
 or "/users/{userId}/settings" etc. each user can only access his own data because of the permission rule

To further automate the process and to ensure that I don't forget the check about userId in the controller, I tried to use spring-data-rest which is great except one problem:

spring-data-rest generates an API-endpoint for each object. They look like this:
"/settings", "/users", "/values".

The paths I want are generated as well:  "/users/{userId}/values" and "/users/{userId}/values" and it correctly checks the userId so it my idea seems to work in principle.

However I can't figure out how to disable the endpoints where the path starts with the child ( "/settings", "/values".) since I only want the endpoints that start with "/users/{userId}" to be available.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to achieve that users can only see and edit their own data?

Here are the classes of my project for testing this scenario (I know that the naming is horrible, I will setup a new project if I know that I can make this work, this is just for testing):

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    //web frontend
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    //rest endpoint generator
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    //database connection
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    //Swagger (/v2/api-docs)
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2")
    //pretty swagger (/swagger-ui.html)
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2")
    //Lombok (automatic getter / setter)
    compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6")
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private String firstName;

  private String lastName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<UserValue> values;

  @OneToOne
  @RestResource(path = "settings", rel = "SettingsRel")
  private Settings settings;
}
```

UserValue:

```
@Entity
public class UserValue {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Integer id;

  String value;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  @JsonIgnore
  private User user;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
}
```

Settings:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Settings {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Integer id;

  private HashMap<String, Object> settings;
}
```

UserValueRepository:

```
public interface UserValueRepository extends CrudRepository<UserValue, Integer> {
}
```

UserRepository:

```
   public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    }
```

SettingsRepository:

```
  public interface SettingsRepository extends CrudRepository<Settings, Integer> {
    }
```

Two additional problems I have with spring-data-rest are that it doesn' seem to work with Swagger and Lombok. So I am even more open to alternative ways to achieve my goal

Comment: Good question, but It'd great if you illustrated it further with more code and less text. Good luck

Comment: Would need to see how you have settings and transactions set up and if you have any repositories for them

Comment: @JSelser & EamonScullion Thank you for your comments. I added my Code and some further comments, I hope they are helpful

Comment: Can you please share your controller class? I am just trying to understand your problem statement

Comment: I don't have any Controllers. The API-endpoints are automatically generated by spring-data-rest. I don't have any more classes than the ones that I show in my question

Comment: Looks like you missing the point for "end points" completely. As Naveen said share your Controller class code. You will decide what end points you want. You should certainly look at this - https://hellokoding.com/full-stack-crud-web-app-and-restful-apis-web-services-example-with-spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-mysql-vuejs-and-docker/

Comment: @AjayKumar Looks like you missing the point for "data-rest-api" completetly. As I said the library generates the endpoints for you so there is no need for controllers. You should certainly look at this - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro

I know how to write Spring Controllers but I wanted to automate this since they are all almost the same. The spring-data-rest endpoints work so without controllers I can still POST, PUT and GET and see updates in the database if the data changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So concerning my original question: There are two ways to achieve the disabling of paths that don't start with "/users/{userId}": Either disabling it directly in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter or using a filter. I used a filter that forwarded for example the request "/settings" to "/users/{idOfLoggedInUser}/settings" and it all worked great for GET-Request.

However it seems that spring-data-rest only processes POST and PUT Request for the root-path of an object, so while GET("/users/{userId}/settings") works without a problem, if you want to POST it needs to be "/settings" and can't be automatically bound to a user.

So it looks like I need to write the Controller manually after all.

However I still found a more elegant solution to the underlying authentication problem than manually selecting the correct user from the database and then setting that user on the given object with @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize in Spring. Both concepts are still a bit tricky for me but they can get the job done and will later be expandable in a very good way for rules like "friends can also see data if you gave them access" or similar things.